# Plotting elements each in individual column on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, histogram

I have an array([13., 23., 33., 48., 52., 48., 33.]).
I want to plot each element each representing an individual column.
Ex. If I have an array of all elements as 10, then I want I column with
all equal height of 10 on the Y-axis.
Instead, what I get is a numerically sorted histogram.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax1.hist(DS) #DS = array([13., 23., 33., 48., 52., 48., 33.])
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  For bars with height 10 with DS as x-positions: `ax1.bar(DS, 10)`. For bars with DS as heights: `ax1.bar(range(len(DS)), DS)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.bar`:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

DS = np.array([13., 23., 33., 48., 52., 48., 33.])
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax1.bar(range(len(DS)), DS)
```

[image]